# How to handle different scenarios across different actions in a Rails controller dried with inherited_resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have the following controller and want to restrict :edit, :update, and :destroy to current_user's own foos.

```
class FooController < InheritedResources::Base
  before_filter :login_required
  respond_to :html

  def show
    @foo = Foo.find params[:id]
    show!
  end

  protected

  def collection
    @foos ||= Foo.all
  end

  def begin_of_association_chain
    current_user
  end
end
```

My simple and perhaps naive question is: Can the above be refactored to look better? It feels like I'm overriding too much of inherited_resources.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting the convenience of building **foo** through the current user I would just use a before_filter (see below).  However, for the edit and destroy actions I would implement a authorization library like [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).

```
class FooController < InheritedResources::Base
  before_filter :login_required      
  before_filter :assign_user, :only => [:create] 
  respond_to :html

  private 
  def assign_user 
    build_resource.user = current_user 
  end
end
```

via: http://groups.google.com/group/inherited_resources/browse_thread/thread/9a2a796a9a1217d4

Answer (score 0):

I typically went with a before filter along the lines of :lookup_foo. (calling it with :except => [:index,:new,:create]). Then I would have a line like @foo = current_user.foos.find(params[:id]).

A similar method can be used for the index action, and both can be adapted to give admin's more access.